# Mule json to java component

Tags: mule

I have this json object

```
data = {    
    "amount": "70",
    "cardNumber": "4222222222222",
    "expiryDate": "1215",
    "currency": "Currency.ISK.alpha" 
}
```

I want to change this json object into java component and with java I want to call various java functions. I'm having problem convert this json object into java component.
I have created two following java classes.

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Handpoint {
private String amount;
private String cardNumber;
private String expireDate;
private String currency;

public String getAmount() { return amount; }
public void setAmount(String amount) { this.amount = amount; }

public String getCardNumber() { return cardNumber; }
public void setCardNumber(String cardNumber) { this.cardNumber = cardNumber; }

public String getExpireDate() { return expireDate; }
public void setExpireDate(String expireDate) { this.expireDate = expireDate; }

public String getCurrency() { return currency; }
public void setCurrency(String currency) { this.currency = currency; }
```

}

and

```
public class HandpointService {
public void ProcessPerson(@Payload Handpoint handpoint) {
    String cardNumber = handpoint.getCardNumber();
    cardNumber.toString();
}
}
```

config file is simple

```
<flow name="json_to_java_componentFlow1" doc:name="json_to_java_componentFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081"     path="json" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <component class="is.threesixtyfive.example.HandpointService" doc:name="Java"/>
</flow>
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Message               : Failed to transform from "json" to 

"is.threesixtyfive.example.Handpoint"
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-109
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Unrecognized field "expiryDate" (Class is.threesixtyfive.example.Handpoint), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@26940a2e; line: 1, column: 98] (through reference chain: is.threesixtyfive.example.Handpoint["expiryDate"]) (org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException)
  org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:53 (null)
2. Failed to transform from "json" to "is.threesixtyfive.example.Handpoint" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.json.transformers.JsonToObject:136 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "expiryDate" (Class is.threesixtyfive.example.Handpoint), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@26940a2e; line: 1, column: 98] (through reference chain: is.threesixtyfive.example.Handpoint["expiryDate"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact:

- the inbound HTTP endpoint is `request-response` so it will return a response to the caller,
- the component method doesn't have a return value.

Mule uses whatever is the current message payload after the component - probably a consumed input stream - to create a response for the inbound endpoint and fails.

If I add:

```
<set-payload value="foo" />
```

after the component then the error clears up (and the HTTP client receives "foo").

Answer (score 1):

The field name differs between the JSON and the POJO. 
In JSON: `expiryDate` 
In the POJO: `expireDate`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo. The error message I get is:
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException: The object transformed is of type: "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*'}", but the expected return type is "SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler, mimeType='application/json'}". The current MuleMessage is null! Please report this to dev@mule.codehaus.org

Comment: The error I get now:
    The object transformed is of type: "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String,
mimeType='*/*'}", but the expected return type is "SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.
api.transport.OutputHandler, mimeType='application/json'}". The current MuleMess
age is null! Please report this to dev@mule.codehaus.org (org.mule.api.transform
er.TransformerException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException). Messag
e payload is of type: Handpoint

Answer (score 0):

i think one way of doing this is first handle the transformation part, by using a transformer JSON to Object and loading you mapping reference, then use a Java Component and load you HandpointService class and make it a callable so you can have an entry point to you class.