# How can i resolve this MULE_ERROR-109

Tags: mule-studio

I am performing a transformation and getting the following error:

ERROR 2013-10-02 12:38:19,763 [[vistaesb].VistaESBFlow1.stage1.04] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:

---

Message               : Failed to transform from "json" to "personal_information"

### Code                  : MULE_ERROR-109

Exception stack is:
1. Unrecognized field "phone_number" (Class personal_information), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@ac7e4af; line: 2, column: 21] (through reference chain: personal_information["phone_number"]) (org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException)
  org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:53 (null)
2. Failed to transform from "json" to "personal_information" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.json.transformers.JsonToObject:136 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)

MY configuration is simple enough:

```
<flow name="VistaESBFlow1" doc:name="VistaESBFlow1">
    <jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint queryKey="personal_information" responseTimeout="1000" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/plain" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="10000" connector-ref="applyVista_dev" doc:name="Data Entry Point">
    </jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="new_mapping_grf" doc:name="DataMapper"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" encoding="utf8" returnClass="personal_information" mimeType="text/plain"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\abrowning\Desktop\test" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" encoding="utf8" mimeType="text/plain"/>
</flow>
```

There is a link to a similar problem here, [109 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108588/mule-json-to-java-component), but i don't think this has to do with my endpoint.

I'm guessing a 109 is a bush-league error, so nay help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The source of my issue was that I had a data mismatch in my get/set methods and after having written a lot of PHP over the last year, I over looked that.